# Use a UIWebView in the background

Tags: iphone

I would like to use a UIWebView object to run custom javascript methods against a local web page. I can do that, but I would like to do it in the background, I mean, while I'm showing a navigation controller or any other content, load webpages and call javascript methods on them.

How would do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in the background" but if you simply want the UIWebView to not be visible, this property is available on all UIView objects:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden
```

Straght from the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW61):

> A hidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events. It remains in 
>   its superview’s list of subviews,
>   however, and participates in
>   autoresizing as usual. Hiding a view
>   with subviews has the effect of hiding
>   those subviews and any view
>   descendants they might have. This
>   effect is implicit and does not alter
>   the hidden state of the receiver’s
>   descendants.
>
> Hiding the view that is the window’s
>   current first responder causes the
>   view’s next valid key view to become
>   the new first responder.
>
> The value of this property reflects
>   the state of the receiver only and
>   does not account for the state of the
>   receiver’s ancestors in the view
>   hierarchy. Thus this property can be
>   NO if the receiver is hidden because
>   an ancestor is hidden.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to do this just by creating a web view in memory and never displaying it. It still exists and works fine.

```
self.backgroundWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
[self.backgroundWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL]];
```

Comment: hi @Dave Batton, how to write this in swift ? thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Once you intialized the webview, d you can easily kick off a background thread, that works the view and loads the page.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(connectToServer) toTarget:self
                               withObject:nil];

.....

(void) connectToServer
{
    // in a different thread....so we need a autoreleasepool
    NSAutoreleasePool *autoreleasepool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ... // do your stuff
    // load HTML on webview
   [autoreleasepool release];
}
```

Comment: This is extremely dangerous. `UIWebView` is a main thread only class and should not be called from a background thread.